# Multicasting on multiple networks

Tags: networking

Say, for example, that I'm part of a multicast group on 239.255.10.10. I'm also connected to two separate networks, one that has a 192.168.0.* and the other 192.168.1.* addressing. Both networks have a clients that is listening for incoming connections and are part of the above mentioned multicast group (because my client has it hardcoded).

When My computer sends out some data to that multicast group, will it be sent out on both networks or will there be some sort of error?

Answer (score 0):

As long as those clients have registered interest in the group via IGMP, they should both receive the data. However, if there is a router between those networks that the multicast data must traverse, it needs to be configured to pass the data. If your computer is the one connected to both networks, it should just work.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - it was about the sending process, not the receiving.